# normal distribution formula conventions

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I sometimes see people write normal distribution formula like this, wondering if $G$ means Gaussian? And what does $C$ means here? Thanks.

$G(\mu, \sigma)$

$\exp(\mu + C(\sigma))$

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Is it possible to give us any reference where do you see the notation?

Comment: Where have you seen the Gaussian written like the second form?

Comment: You **need** to provide a source. They could be **ANYTHING**.

Comment: @SiongthyeGoh, vote up. I just see people write on whiteboard during a discussion. Is it popular form of writing Gaussian distribution? I do not see too much before and it is why I come here to ask. :)

Comment: @GrahamKemp, vote up. I just see people write on whiteboard during a discussion. Is it popular form of writing Gaussian distribution? I do not see too much before and it is why I come here to ask. :)

Comment: @probablyme, vote up. I just see people write on whiteboard during a discussion. Is it popular form of writing Gaussian distribution? I do not see too much before and it is why I come here to ask. :)

Comment: It's certainly _possible_ but I don't know if it is popular. I am familiar with $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

Comment: @probablyme, your form is normally what I wrote. What do you guess $C$ means here?

Comment: @LinMa What was the discussion *about*, and are you sure you've remembered the expression correctly? $~$  The nearest expression I can match would be that the *Moment Generating Function* for a Gaussian/Normal Distribution is: $\exp(\mu t + \tfrac 1 2 \sigma^2 t^2)$

Comment: @LinMa Are you sure about the plus sign ? Couldn´t it be a comma as well ?

Comment: @callculus, vote up. I am sure about the plus sign, just some tech talk and a bit lost by the formula. If you have any ideas about the meaning of $C$ and $G$, it will be great. :)

Comment: @LinMa $C(\sigma)$ could have the meaning of the multivariate covariance matrix. And for $G$ I agree with  the other users that $G $ is the (multivariate) Gaussian.

Comment: Thanks @callculus, vote up. If $C(\sigma)$ means multivariate covariance matrix, how $exp(\mu+C(\sigma))$ could be used to represent a normal distribution?

Comment: @LinMa That´s the next question. We all have to think further ahead. Thanks for the upvote of my previous comments.

Comment: @callculus, thanks and vote up. Let us go back to your original question, why do you think $C(\sigma)$  is multivariate covariance matrix? If you have some quote for document/reference, it will be great.

Comment: @LinMa Note that it was only a guess. I´m far away to be sure. I don´t have not really a reference. I have only found a wiki page where C is mentioned as an abbreviation of the covariance:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Table_of_symbols_and_abbreviations

Comment: Thanks @callculus, nice reference and vote up, but how co-variance matrix is related to normal distribution formula here?

Comment: @GrahamKemp, thanks for the hint of moment generating function. My understanding of moment generating function is still in theory level, and wondering when you analyze normal distribution, how you usually use moment generating function, besides CDF and PDF of normal distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there can be a definite answer unless we find the person who wrote it there and asked him or her.

I am guessing that $G$ refers to Gaussian.

Could $\mu+C(\sigma)$ be a confidence interval?

and the person might want to know what is the image of this interval under exponential map?

Comment: Thanks SiongthyeGoh, vote up. Wondering how confidence interval is related to $\sigma$ in normal distribution?

Comment: BTW, for your comments, "exponential map", what do you mean by **map**?

Comment: It could be the typical $( \mu - 1.96 \sigma, \mu+1.96 \sigma )$ right? but still we are just guessing.

Comment: oh, I meant function.

Comment: Thanks SiongthyeGoh, vote up for your both replies. In your reply, confidence interval is related to both $\mu$ and $\sigma$, but in $C(\sigma)$, it seems only related to $\sigma$?

Comment: I am not sure whether they use notation $a+(b,c)=(a+b,a+c)$. The best way to find out is really to ask the person who wrote it.

Comment: Thanks SiongthyeGoh, vote up for your reply. How you sample about $a+(b,c)$ is related to my question about why $C$ has only parameter $\sigma$, but not two parameters $\sigma$ and $\mu$?

Comment: Let $a=\mu, (b,c)=1.96(-\sigma, \sigma)$. Hmmm.... do you have a picture of the white board? we might be misguiding you. $C(\sigma)$ can really just be a complicated term that involved $\sigma$ which can really just be anything. What do you intend to do after you figure out the formula?

Comment: Thanks SiongthyeGoh, in statistics, you mean when we see $C(\sigma)$ could be anything? I mean no definite abbreviation for $C(\sigma)$, correct?

Comment: Yes, for maths and statistics. We have to look for the context, which is absent in this case.

Comment: Thanks SiongthyeGoh for the patience, mark your reply as answer.